Can a combustion engine be converted to an electric air compressor by using an electric motor to drive the crankshaft through the flywheel?
I know you need to replace valves and all that and this probably isn't efficient but assuming you wanted to do this to a 2.0l N/A Inline 4 engine and running it at 3500rpm and 200 psi, what hp motor would you need and how much cfm could be achieved ??

You will want to start with the calculations of displacement. What volume is moved by the pistons per revolution of the crankshaft? If you'll be running at 3500 rpm, multiply the single revolution value by that number to get the displacement to convert to cubic feet per minute. Also research "jake brake" to learn what is involved in converting an ICE to a compressor.

Only for low pressure. The valve seat on the exhaust is turned the wrong way round for a compressor.

Roughly
Assuming you convert to 2 stroke
3500 rpm/60=60 rps
air pumped in = 60*2 l/s
work done per litre of intake air = 1 l x deltap
= .001*(200-15)*10^5/15 J
=1200J
Hence power required about 120*1200=150 kW
For cfm your 200 psi air is roughly 1/15 of 120 l/s, 32 cfm
This is very crude, but as you can see the power is going to be expensive so a properly designed pump would probably be cost effective.

Since this is starting as a four cycle engine, I expect the resulting air compressor would take in the displacement (2.0 liters) every other revolution of the crankshaft or 1.0 liter per revolution. That works out to (using units I remember off hand):
$airflow_{inlet} = 1 liter \times \frac{1000 cm^3}{liter} \times \frac{in^3}{{2.54}^3cm^3} \times \frac{ft^3}{{12}^3 in^3} \times 3500\frac{rev}{min} \times = 123 \frac{ft^3}{min}$
If the output will be 200 psig or (about) 215 psia and the input air will be (about) 14.7 psia, the output volume will be on the order of:
$123 \frac{ft^3}{min} \times \frac{14.7}{215} = 8.5 \frac{ft^3}{min} @ 200 psig$
A measure of power will be about
$200 \frac{lb}{in^2} \times \frac{8.5 ft^3}{min} \times \frac{12^2 in^2}{ft^2} \times \frac{1 min}{60 sec} \times \frac{1 hp}{550 ft lb/sec} = 7.4 hp$
If we were working with something (mostly) incompressible like water, that would be the required power.  The bad news is for this it is no where near right.  Being compressible and a non-ideal gas, air heats up as it is compressed and that has to be taken into account.
The magic formula (found here or here) for adiabatic (no heat transfer) air compression is:
$HP = \frac{144 N P V_n k}{33000(k-1)} \times [(\frac{P_2}{P})^{\frac{k-1}{Nk}} -1]$
where

HP is horsepower
N is number of stages (1 for this problem)
P is inlet pressure psia (14.7 psia)
$V_n$ is flow of input in CFM (123 scfm)
k is adiabatic expansion coefficient (1.41 for air)
$P_2$ is outlet pressure psia 215 psia

substituting and working it out we get:
$HP = \frac{144(1)(14.7)(123)(1.41)}{33000(1.41-1)} \times [(\frac{214.7}{14.7})^{\frac{1.41-1}{(1)(1.41)}} -1] = 32.0 hp$
Wow, that's a lot of power but don't worry, you won't get anywhere near 200 psig.  I would expect with a compression ratio of 10:1 which is common for 2 liter engines, you might get 50 psig, depending upon the cylinder geometry.  For the equations, that comes out to 14.8 hp, still a lot. You are going to drive this with another 2 liter engine, No?

Why do you think you'd get fifty psi, as opposed to say 120 psi gauge? Good point about 2 stroke vs four stroke,  though. Old honey-dipper tank trucks used to put V-6 heads on a 460 cid V-8 and then rig the other two cylinders as a vacuum pump. But I can't think of an automotive ICE compressor conversion, only old 2 strokes like WWI radials. You normally ran two or three cylinders in series to form a two/three stage compressor with intercooling. https://dothan.craigslist.org/tls/d/gordon-ingersoll-rand-radial-engine/7759108409.html

Chrysler Airtemp refrigeration compressor from 1934 - "Chrysler Airtemp created a radial compressor design which was inspired by and resembled the radial aircraft engines used in the war. The Airtemp radial compressor was much quieter than the aircraft engines. Chrysler bragged that the balanced radial design made them so smooth you could balance a penny on them. But, their best and most important feature was the unique automatic capacity control." https://refresearch.com/the-chrysler-airtemp-radial-compressor/

@PhilSweet, if you have a 1:10 compression ratio, you take in 0 PSIG air and (assuming isothermal compression, which it is not) the best you can do is get 100 PSIG output.  I was trying to give the OP an idea of power for lower pressures.  The real gain would be by piping the cylinders into each other to make a four stage compressor.  If cylinder #2 compresses the output from #1, etc, it is more efficient and you might be able to get 200 PSIG.

@PhilSweet that radial engine and compressor would be great fun if I had lots of time and money I did not know what to do with (I have neither).  The smoothest engine was the 1963 Chrysler Turbo see the Jay Leno video.  At 16:47, he puts a glass of water on top of the engine.  Turbine cars are the technology of the future (and always will be).

Why wouldn't he update the CR to get 20:1 or so, or use a diesel?

@GregLocock, Updating the compression ratio is not a small matter, you have to replace the crankshaft or pistons or both.  The OP said Naturally Aspirated 2.0l Inline 4 engine which for gasoline engines, a common compression ratio is 10:1.  Diesels of that size are not as easy to come by but a diesel a compression ratio on the order of 20:1 is common.  So, yes, if the OP can find a diesel, they will be all set.

@user1683793 Atmospheric pressure is 0 psig or 14.7 psia.  Use absolute pressure here. 10:1 compression would be about 147 psia if isothermal, 251 psia if adiabatic. Converting back to gage pressure yields 133 and 236 psig respectively, but there is valve overlap and leakage, of course.

@PhilSweet, I stand corrected, For isothermal, 147 would be right, one atmosphere compressed 10:1 gives 147 psia.  How did you arrive at the 251?

@user1683793 Or skim the head.

@GregLocock Good grief, I'm having a terrible time with answers here.  Quite so.  If you machined down the top of the block or under the head, while paying attention to the piston and valve clearance (and avoiding lubrication/cooling passages), you could (relatively) easily increase the compression ratio.  Could you get to 20:1? Maybe, I guess that depends upon the insides of the block and head.

This is one of those cases where I paid attention in thermodynamics class in 19_xx_ and remember a bit but never applied it (I did control systems before moving to computers).  I enjoy thinking about problems like this but once in a while, I come up with something like my 100psi statement that is completely goofy.  Thank you for the corrections.

The reason you are having a terrible time is that you don't seem to have any practical experience of engines. Yes, you can easily modify CR. small diesels are commonly available, I owned my first in 1984, and have had about 6 since then, including my current car. Given the amount of effort new camshafts etc are, the prospect of new piston/machining the head or whatever is small bikkies.
